# Android: How to create task to generate icons form source files in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a few SVG files that I use to generate drawable resources (specifically icons) at different screen densities.

Is there a way that I can automate this task with Gradle?

I am pretty new to gradle, and have run into two main things that I am stuck on:

1. What task do I make my task a dependency of in the android project (and how)?
2. The code for the tasks for each icon will be essentially the same, apart from the input, outputs, and sizes. How can I create these tasks and avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I believe the way to do this is via variant configuration as described in the [Gradle Android Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Advanced-Build-Customization)

So something like:

```
android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
     variant.someStandardTask.dependsOn yourCustomTask
}
```

I'm not sure what standard task you want to use but 'processResources' seems like a likely candidate to me...

2) Declare a new task Type and then create tasks that are instances of that type and configure them differently. See the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#N164A1) for a simple example.

Comment: I got 2 to work, but am still unsuccessful with 1. After adding my task as a dependency of mergeResources or processResources, it is never actually run. I think the problem is I don't know where to put the android.applicationVariants.each code.